# Is editable=False required?

Tags: python, django

I am developing a model, the only actions that can be performed on an instance of it are view and delete.

Moreover, all these actions must take place in the StackedInline, which is bound to the ModelAdmin class of another model.

**Model example**:

```
class IncludingModel(models.Model):
    ...


class ReadAndDeleteOnlyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.TextField(verbose_name="First field", editable=False)
    field2 = models.TextField(verbose_name="Second field", editable=False)

    including_model_instance = models.ForeignKey(IncludingModel, related_name="read_and_delete_only_instances")
```

**Admin example**

```
class ReadAndDeleteOnlyModelInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ReadAndDeleteOnlyModel
    readonly_fields = ("field1", "field2")

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj):
        return False


@admin.register(IncludingModel)
class IncludingModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    inlines = (ReadAndDeleteOnlyModelInline,)
```

Interaction with ReadAndDeleteOnlyModel instances occurs only in IncludingModelAdmin. After removing editable = False, my fields are still read-only due to the fact that I specified them in readonly_fields. This begs the question, is editable = False needed in my case?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter editable is True by default. If you change it to False, the field will not be displayed in the admin or any other ModelForm. They are also skipped during model validation.